# Hiding input values when slider goes to end

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using JQuery UI SLider for a price range slider.

I want to hide values by default on loading page and when user slides the slider it should show the values in input field but after going to the maximum and minimum value it should again hide input values.

Code for slider:

```
$("#price-slider").slider({
    range: true,
    animate: true,
    min: 1000,
    max: 500000,
    values: [1000, 500000],
    create: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
        $("#amountx").val("" + ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
        $("#amountx").focus();
    }

});
```

This is HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 slider-lbl">
     <div class="spacer-b15">
        <label for="amountx">Price range:</label>
            <input type="text" name="pprice" id="amountx" class="slider-input" onfocus="return getFinderData();">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 slider-cntnt">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="slider-wrapper black-slider">
            <div id="slider-range"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Screenshots:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your related HTML codes and a screenshot of what is going on with the range slider?

Comment: I've submitted HTM, Screenshot, what will be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In you slider object, there is the method called "slide()" so in this method you can check if the slide values are max and min. Then you can show it or hide it.

It would be something like this;

```
$("#price-slider").slider({
    range: true,
    animate: true,
    min: 1000,
    max: 500000,
    values: [1000, 500000],
    create: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
        $("#amountx").val("" + ui.values[0] + "-" + ui.values[1]);
        if((ui.values[0] == 1000) && (ui.values[1] == 500000)){
          $("#amountx").hide();
        }else{
          $("#amountx").show();
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        valtooltip($(this), ui);
        $("#amountx").focus();
    }

});
```

I have no way to actually test it, so keep me updated if it is going to work.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. I'm going to apply it on other sliders and i hope it will work fine on all sliders thanks a lot.